# how to do android dialog flip animation

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation

I have an android dialog with button "feedback"

I want the user to write his input.

how can I create flip animation to flip this dialog a "enter feedback" dialog ?

I have tried:

```
private void flipCard() {
    View rootLayout = (View) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_root);
    View cardFace = (View) mDialog
            .findViewById(R.id.main_activity_card_face);
    View cardBack = (View) mDialog
            .findViewById(R.id.main_activity_card_back);

    FlipAnimation flipAnimation = new FlipAnimation(cardFace, cardBack);

    if (cardFace.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        flipAnimation.reverse();
    }
    rootLayout.startAnimation(flipAnimation);
}
```